# Apache Solr TermsComponent: How to prevent from splitting words after one character. E.g. "t-shirt"

Tags: solr, split, character, cpu-word

I'm trying to get autosuggestions for search terms. But I#ve run into a problem with words containing characters like "-" and "&" which are being splitted after just one character.

Example:

```
/solr/terms/?terms=true&terms.fl=item&terms.limit=10&terms.sort=count&terms.prefix=t

<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="terms">
        <lst name="item">
            <int name="top">11335</int>
            <int name="tshirt">10249</int>
            <int name="t">10156</int>
            <int name="trouser">4771</int>
            <int name="tight">1577</int>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

The problem lies with **tshirt** and **t**. "t" only appears within "t-shirt". so how do I prevent Solr from splitting words just after one character if there is no whitespace after it. "t shirt" should split - "t-shirt" and "h&m" should not.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, how do the rules apply for 'AT&T' and 'O(n)'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field type for items seems to be text with [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) being one of the filters in the analysis.
WordDelimiterFilterFactory by default will split on Intra word delimiters.
So t-shirt would generate two tokens t and shirt, and hence the term t appears for you.

If you want to use terms for autosuggest, remove or tune the WordDelimiterFilterFactory as per the requirement.
You can use the TextField with basic configurations, like with  WhitespaceTokenizerFactory and apply the lower, ascii folding filters on it so the tokens are least analyzed and don't appear fragmented.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add words you don't want to be split by adding them to protwords.txt or map certain characters in wdfftypes.txt so they won't be used to split terms.

Also check this link for good AutoSuggester http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only problem you have using the `TermsComponent` to make auto suggestions the answer you got is perfect, but I'd like to propose an alternative answer.

The `TermsComponent` is fast and pretty easy to use, but it has the following limitations:

- you can't apply any filter to your suggestions;
- you may have trouble with case-sensitive queries: for example, if you use the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` and index the word `Word`, you'll get the suggestion only typing `w` and not `W`. You basically need to take care of lowering the query before submitting it to solr, since you can't apply any tokenizer or filter to your query.

Depending on your requirements, you might want to consider different ways to make auto suggestions with Solr. The [Different ways to make auto suggestions with Solr](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr) article should be useful in order to make the right choice.